# FSCalendarScopeWeek issue- swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm using fscalender on my project which I have to use both month scope and week scope on different view controller.so when I'm using week scope date title size is getting smaller, but when I increase the view height its getting perfect.but my view should have an fixed size so how can I fix this problem.

[this is my calendar now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91351.png)

here I converted the round background to rectangle by

```
calendarObj.appearance.borderRadius = 0
```

The above week title is implemented with stackview.

[This is actually I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CEj9.png)

the rectangle border is not showing full.How to resolve this?Im new to this iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried This On A view, I have Added only Few Lines, an it is working as you want.

```
    calendarView.dataSource = self
    calendarView.delegate = self
    calendarView.scrollDirection = .vertical
    calendarView.scope = .week
    calendarView.backgroundColor = .clear
    calendarView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    calendarView.appearance.selectionColor  = .none
    calendarView.appearance.borderSelectionColor = .red
    calendarView.appearance.todayColor = .clear
    calendarView.appearance.titleTodayColor = .black
    calendarView.appearance.weekdayTextColor = .black
    calendarView.appearance.borderRadius = 0.2
```

[image: Check My Output]

[image: Here's Another Image]

I Hope This Will Help.